# How can I open the collapsing div through prop?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, redux

I have a react-bootstrap Collapse that should open/close when clicking the button. I also want to open it through a redux dispatch but for simplicity I am passing a property with a bool value:

```
 <App opennow={true} />
```

This is part of the render method in my Appcomponent:

```
 render() {
    console.log('opennow', this.props.opennow)

    //this.state.open = this.props.opennow;
    console.log(this.state.open);
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={ 
            ()=> 
      this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
                        }>
          click
        </Button>
        <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
          <div>
```

How can I keep the existing show/hide functionality and trigger a show ie open the Collapse through a property in this case this.props.opennow? Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/QGKKoE?editors=1111)

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to pass in the bool from the app bootstrapping level and instead use redux to control the open and close of the collapsing? If so you just set up an action/reducer and set a part of the state with a bool (or whatever) to control it, just like any other action you would set up with redux/react. Are you trying to use the **component local state and redux?** it's not clear to me what kind of solution you are asking for. If you can specify more I can provide you with a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `componentDidMount` in your class. It runs code after the DOM has been generated.

```
 componentDidMount(){
     if(this.props.opennow){
       this.setState({open:true})
     }
  }
```

If the `opennow` prop is passed as true it checks the condition and sets the `open` to true in the state.

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/mrinalmech/pen/MbjbYv?editors=1111)

Comment: I am using redux dispatch to pass props would this be the same event?

Comment: Ok so when you change `opennow` using a redux dispatch you want the change to be reflected I am assuming? ie you fire the dispatch which changes `opennow` (which is a redux state variable) then you want the modal to open or close.

Use `componentWillReceiveProps()`. Just like `componentDidMount` is called when the component is first initialized `componentWillReceiveProps` is called when the props have changed.